# Redis Cluster Installation Issue

Tags: ruby, redis, fedora, fedora-23

I am a linux(fedora) user and I installed latest stable version of redis.

I run command  `redis-server` and is working fine.

Also `redis-cli ping` is giving PONG as expected output.

However when i am starting a cluster nothing is working.

```
./redis-trib.rb create --replicas 1 127.0.0.1:7000 127.0.0.1:7001 127.0.0.1:7002 127.0.0.1:7003 127.0.0.1:7004 127.0.0.1:7005
```

is given below error

> /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- redis (LoadError)     from
>   /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`
>   require'     from ./redis-trib.rb:25:in `'

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem and is solved id as below.

```
cd git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc echo 'eval "$(rbenv init
-)"' >> ~/.bashrc exec $SHELL

git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc exec $SHELL

git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-gem-rehash.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-gem-rehash

rbenv install 2.3.0 rbenv global 2.3.0 ruby -v gem install bundler

gem install redis
```

Answer (score 0):

As [this](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1528) suggests, there might be a problem with your ruby installation

Comment: How to rebuild ruby ?... i resinatll it but of now use